# Why is a segmentation fault occurring in this variable-sized array code?

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve [this variable-sized array problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/variable-sized-arrays/problem), but get a segmentation fault. I tried searching for a solution but couldn't find the reason why this doesn't work.

To reproduce the error simply copy the code below and paste it into the editor under the link above.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
//using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;

    // handle n lines representing the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        std::string line;
        getline(std::cin, line);
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int enterNumber;
        while (iss >> enterNumber)
        {
            numbers.push_back(enterNumber);
        }

        arr.push_back(numbers);
    }

    // handle q lines representing i, j
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        std::cout << arr[x][y];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? Why doesn't it work?

Input that causes the segmentation fault:

```
2 2
3 1 5 4
5 1 2 8 9 3
0 1
1 3
```

Expected output:

```
5
9
```

Comment: Did you compile this with all possible warnings turned on, then make sure there were no warnings before trying to compile and then run it?

Comment: There is no guarantee that `x` and `y` exist. Perhaps adding a check would help?

Comment: @RandomDavis Hackerrank's editor shows no warning for this code.

Comment: The values of n, q and x,y you are entering are possibly invalid. You should be looking at the size of the factor using  vectors methods, not entering values  yourself. Also, you are not going to learn C++ from sites such as Hackerrank.

Comment: Could you paste the input used when you get the segmentation fault??

Comment: Most probably, an out-of-range exception for vector.

Comment: Change the one line to:  `std::cout << arr.at(x).at(y);`, which will throw a std::out_of_range for you.

Comment: At this point you should use a debugger to step through the code line by line and find out when the program first does something unexpected. Regardless of whether hackerrank provides one, you will need a debugger to program effectively.

Comment: @Eljay There should be no out-of-range error for these inputs.

Comment: The problem statement guarantees that the values for n, q, x, y are fine (not ouf of bounds or anything weird). I believe the code fails during the first for loop while trying to build the 2D array.

Comment: I don't agree with the expected output. You have `n=2, q=2` and then (based on your code) are attempting to print the 1st entry in the 0th vector (which should be a 1) and then the 3rd entry in the 1st vector (which should be an 8).

Comment: Time to debug the code!

Comment: @MaxLanghof Note that the first value of those n lines in the input is `k` which tells us how many values are following (see problem description where input format is described).

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Then that's something that your code is not implementing correctly. You are never reading `k`, your code treats it as one of the numbers to store in the vector.

Comment: @MaxLanghof That's another issue (not related to the segmentation fault). See the question's answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To fix the segmentation fault simply add `std::cin.get();` after the first `std::cin`(third line in your main function).

The segmentation fault happened because `getline(std::cin, line);`returned an empty string during the first iteration of the for loop. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718017/clearing-a-carriage-return-from-memory-in-c).

Note that even after fixing the segmentation fault issue your code is still wrong (doesn't solve the challenge) :p

Try this:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
//using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, q;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    std::cin.get();

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> arr;

    // handle n lines representing the arrays
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::vector<int> numbers;
        std::string line;
        getline(std::cin, line);
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int enterNumber;
        while (iss >> enterNumber)
        {
            numbers.push_back(enterNumber);
        }

        numbers.erase(numbers.begin());  // because first value is k
        arr.push_back(numbers);
    }

    // handle q lines representing i, j
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        std::cout << arr[x][y] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) `getline(std::cin, line);` . Line contains space and numbers.

2) Handle spaces in lines

3) Handle first int in line for array length. (You tried to add array length in array itself)

Here is working code for reference. (Passed all test cases)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, q;
    cin >> n >> q;
    vector< vector<int> > arr;

    int temp, array_count;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        vector<int> numbers;
        cin>>array_count;
        for(int j = 0; j < array_count; j++) {
            cin>>temp;
            numbers.push_back(temp);
        }
        arr.push_back(numbers);
        numbers.clear();
    }

    // handle q lines representing i, j
    int x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
        cin >> x >> y;
        cout << arr[x][y]<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```